# How to create images dynamically with labels in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have to create images dynamically with its label i.e hyperlinks. For that i have written code as follows but its not displaying images, it displays labels (hyperlinks) only.

```
string fname="";
        string fpath = "";
        DataSet dsfile = new DataSet();
//For fetching data that is inserted earlier in database

        SqlDataAdapter dafile = new SqlDataAdapter("select FileName,FilePath from CRM_CustomerAttachment where CustomerID='" + cust + "'", FlyCon);
        dafile.Fill(dsfile);
        if (dsfile != null)
        {
            fname = Convert.ToString(dsfile.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FileName"]);
            fpath = Convert.ToString(dsfile.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FilePath"]);
        }

        PlaceHolder PHFilename = (PlaceHolder)FVViewCustData.FindControl("PHFilename");//FVViewCustData is formview & placeholder is inside the formview
        for (int i = 0; i < dsfile.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            HyperLink hypname = new HyperLink();
            hypname.Text = Convert.ToString(dsfile.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FileName"]) + "</br>";
            PHFilename.Controls.Add(hypname);
            Image img = new Image();
            img.ImageUrl =  Convert.ToString(dsfile.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FilePath"]);           
            PHFilename.Controls.Add(img);
    }
```

Asp.net C#.
Please help me? Thank you.

Comment: did you check path is it right or not ? most of cases image not display because of wrong path

Answer (score 0):

hers is code

```
Dim img As New Image
        img.ID = "img1"
        img.ImageUrl = "http://www.prodeveloper.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/stackoverflow-logo-250.png"
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(img)
```

Comment: path is coming correctly here i added my ip address plus my folder name plus that string (Convert.ToString(dsfile.Tables[0].Rows[i]["FilePath"])) then also its not displaying whats the wrong with that?

Comment: i use  Dim img As New Image
        img.ID = "img1"
        img.ImageUrl = "http://www.prodeveloper.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/stackoverflow-logo-250.png"
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(img)

Comment: Dim img As New Image
       img.ID = "img1"
        img.ImageUrl = "http://www.prodeveloper.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/stackoverflow-logo-250.png"
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(img) code is work fine

Comment: Can you send me and path of image which is display in image dynamically ?

Comment: what about the label?